# Routing Error when the Route exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I get this routing error when loading the page:

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Videos#index

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #26 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}
```

It is referring to this line:

```
<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path(current_user.profile), :class => 'normal' %>
```

However, the route exists because I have this in my routes:

```
resources :profiles do
    get 'activity', :on => :member
    get 'shown_songs', :on => :member
end
```

and I have this action in my profiles controller:

```
def show
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end
```

What's going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're passing a nil object to your url helper, you will see this error. Check that current_user.profile isn't nil in this line:

```
profile_path(current_user.profile)
```